# Lucas-Lehmer Mersenne numbers with Python

Tags: python-3.x

Writing a Python code that checks Mersenne numbers using Lucas-Lehmer test.

```
def lucas_lehmer(p):
 my_list=[4]
 value=2**p-1
 lucas=4
 for val in range(1, p - 1):
    lucas=(lucas*lucas-2)%value
 if lucas== 0:
        my_list.apprend(lucas)
 else: 
  break
 print(my_list)
 print(lucas)
```

The code shown above only show gives the result for the first iteration, regardless of the p value selected. I want to be able to display all the Lehmer test values within the given value of p, in this case 17.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think the problem is not doing the append in the loop but only when `p` is a prime number. Your formatting is somewhat off, so I'm not 100% sure if I'm right. Additionally, you have a typo in `append`. I added some code to print the actual result of the primality test.

```
def lucas_lehmer(p):
    my_list=[4]
    value=2**p-1
    lucas=4
    for val in range(1, p - 1):
        lucas = ((lucas*lucas)-2) % value
        my_list.append(lucas)
    if lucas == 0:
        print("prime")
    else:
        print("composite")
    print(my_list)
    print(lucas)
```

Calling `lucas_lehmer(7)` leads to the following output:

```
prime
[4, 14, 67, 42, 111, 0]
0
```

Comment: This help. Thank you so much!